# How to get deployment status of Email in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api, metadata-api

I am new to SFMC world. Is there a methods to query SFMC via API calls to ascertain the completion status of jobs?

For example I need to get all jobs for today, who's status is complete.

Comment: What do you mean by "deployment"? Is it the actual send of the email? If yes - what type of send are we talking about (as there are multiple options for an email being sent).

Comment: Yes, I its email being sent status.

Comment: You should update your question with additional details. A.o: are you using transactional API? Guided Send? How do you expect to identify the email, where you need to retrieve the sent status?

Comment: Also - how do you define "status"? Is it just whether the emails has been sent? Or how many subscribers received it? What if the same email has been sent more than once? You really need to be more precise in your question, describing your actual use case - and preferably including some details about your research and attempts so far.